# how to find touchmove change to other objects

Tags: javascript, html

I have get target in mousemove event that it's fine but I am not getting target in touchleave event for ipad and android.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<svg width="300" height="200" style="border:0px solid #ccc;">
    <polygon id="a" points="100,10 40,198 190,78 10,78 160,198" style="fill:lime;stroke:purple;stroke-width:5;fill-rule:evenodd;" />
</svg>

<script>

document.getElementById('a').addEventListener('mousemove', function(e) {
    document.getElementById("a").style.fill = 'red';
}, false);

document.getElementById('a').addEventListener('mouseleave', function(e) {
    document.getElementById("a").style.fill = 'lime';
}, false);

document.getElementById('a').addEventListener('touchmove', function(e) {
   document.getElementById("a").style.fill = 'red';
}, false);

document.getElementById('a').addEventListener('touchleave', function(e) {
   document.getElementById("a").style.fill = 'lime';
}, false);

</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no such thing as a "touchleave" event. Apparently there was a proposed spec for it but [it was never implemented](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/touchleave). If you want to know when a user touch leaves an area, the best thing to do would be to manually track touchmove events and figure it out from there.

Answer (score 0):

There are three events for touch.

1. touchstart
2. touchmove
3. touchend

And please be aware of 'ghost clicks' when using touch events!

Answer (score 0):

Since your `svg` surrounds the polygon on all sides, you could do this:

Put the touchmove event on the svg:

```
var svg = document.querySelector('svg');
var polygon = document.getElementById("a");

svg.addEventListener('touchmove', function(e) {
   if (e.target === polygon) { 
      // touch is inside polygon
      polygon.style.fill = 'red';
   } else {
      // touch is outside polygon
      polygon.style.fill = 'lime';
   }
}, false);
```

(for this code to work in all browsers, you will have to modify it a bit)